# Exhuastion before and after workout

Tags: energy, genetics

I have been working out for 2 weeks and I have noticed that I am very lazy. Even though I take supplements I tend to stay so lazy that except for gym time, I don't get off the couch. Except the gym, I have no physical activity. The reason is I feel too lazy and down. 
I had my test and I am fine. Sometimes I feel so tired that workout too feels like a burden. It's like i am wasting or wasted. I am 29 and i am 78.5 kg. What can the problem be? Can it be genetic? As my mother sleeps too much or where I was bought up? What should i do to make myself feel energetic and powerful? 
Even when I wake up, I feel too down or wasted energy. Any test or routine changes I can make?

Comment: You said you had your test and you are fine: What tests did you have done?

Comment: Maybe you're lazy, depressed, or just stressed. The last 2 can't be addressed on this site; as for laziness, there are things you can do. But that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your hormone levels, etc are all normal, caffeine may help to get you going before a workout. I find that when I have to do a workout when I'm worn out or not motivated, a bit of caffeine will help me get going (though at some point you have to be able to motivate yourself to keep going). There are [studies](http://www.acsm.org/docs/current-comments/caffeineandexercise.pdf) showing that caffeine can help to increase performance and endurance as well.

Comment: It is old, but I have to understand how much caffeine is good and how much is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Well done on getting to the gym if you are feeling like this. 
I would suggest a couple of things.
Try to get out for a daily walk, getting some fresh air will make you feel more energised.

You didn't say whether of not you are working, if not, try to find a hobby, or set yourself a goal for fitness or something else you can be working towards.

If this doesn't improve soon, go back to your Doctor. It's not normal to feel like this all the time.  I'm no Doctor, but you could be depressed.

Try to help yourself, and if that doesn't work, keep going back to the doctors until you get some answers.